# Error al crear un array: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

Tengo este código:

```
import json
import pickle
import random

import nltk
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('punkt')  # Downloadthe punkt tokenizer
nltk.download('stopwords')  # Download the stopwords list

with open('Untitled4.json') as json_file:
  intents = json.load(json_file)

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '¿', '.']

for intent in intents['intents']:
  for pattern in intent['patterns']:
    word_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)  # Tokenize the pattern
    words.extend(word_tokens)  # Add tokens to the words list
    documents.append((word_tokens, intent['tag']))  # Add the pattern and tag to the documents list
    if intent['tag'] not in classes:
      classes.append(intent['tag'])  # Add the tag to the classes list

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]  # Lemmatize and filter words
words = sorted(set(words))  # Sort and remove duplicates

pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))  # Save the words list to a pickle file
pickle.dump(classes, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))  # Save the classes list to a pickle file

training = []  # Create the training data
for document in documents:
  bag = []  # Create a bag of words for the current document
  for word in words:
    bag.append(1) if word in document[0] else bag.append(0)  # Set the value to 1 if the word exists in the document, otherwise 0
  output_row = [0] * len(classes)  # Create an output row with zeros
  output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1  # Set the value to 1 for the corresponding class
  training.append([bag, output_row])  # Add the bag of words and output row to the training data

random.shuffle(training)  # Shuffle the training data
training = np.array(training) #Convert the training data to a numpy array

train_x = list(training[:, 0])  # Extract the input data (bag of words)
train_y = list(training[:, 1])  # Extract the target data (output row)

model = Sequential()  # Create a sequential model
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))  # Add a first dense layer with 128 neurons and ReLU activation
model.add(Dropout(0.5))  # Add dropout with a rate of 0.5
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0])))  # Add a second dense layer with the number of classes
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])  # Compile the model

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=8)  # Train the model for 100 epochs with a batch size of 8

model.save('chatbot_model.h5')  # Save the trained model to a file
```

Con este JSON:

```
{
   "intents": [
    {

             "tag":"saludo",
        "patterns": ["hola", "Buenos días", "que tal","buen dia","hey","hey bro","Que pasa?","Saludos"],
        "responses":["¿Que puedo hacer para que no me molestes?","¿Que quieres tu?","(Resoplo) ¿Que pasa?","¿Que pasa ahora?"]

    },
    {          "tag":"nombre",
        "patterns": ["como te llamas","what,s your name"],
        "responses":["","","","","",""]
     }
]

}
```

Y me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/home/runner/N/main.py", line 49, in <module>  
    training = np.array(training)  
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (10, 2) + inhomogeneous part.
```

En el json tengo las responses completas pero no puedo mostrarlo.
¿Habría alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Comment: Estas intentando crear un array que no tiene el mismo numero de elementos por dimension, es decir, que no es homogéneo. Por ejemplo: `np.array([[[1], [0]], [[1, 1], [0, 1]]])`. Puedes crear un array de listas con `training = np.array(training, dtype=object)`, aunque entonces numpy pierde gran parte de su atractivo...

Comment: De todas formas, si solo usas el array de numpy para obtener por separado las columnas, puedes conseguir lo mismo sin NumPy con `train_x, train_y = (list(col) for col in zip(*training))`

Comment: Gracias, es una versión de la ia que estaba creando.